# How to breakup an activerecord dataset into two halves using one query with RAILS 2.3.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

The dataset looks like this (Model WF with id, widget_id,feature_id,status as fields)

id   widget_id    feature_id    status

---

1      1           23           1

2      1           45           1

3      1           89           1

4      2           41           1

5      1           10           0

6      1           90           0

7      1           83           0

8      2           45           1

What could be my activerecord query which allows me to write one statement and the result groups itself into something like this ( filter on the basis of status)

a,b = [23,45,89,41,45][10,90,83]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this with only one SQL query, use [group_by](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
all_grouped = WF.all(:select => 'feature_id, status').group_by(&:status)
```

This will return you an OrderedHash with two key/value pairs (assuming status is either 0 or 1). The key of each pair will be the status and the value will be an array of WF instances having that status.

You can further manipulate the returned [OrderedHash](http://rdoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/ActiveSupport/OrderedHash) using any [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) method (like sort, sort_by, map, etc.)

To get the output you want as a, b you need to add the following lines:

```
a = all_grouped.select{ |k, v| k == 1 }[0].last.map(&:feature_id) # select WFs with status == 1 and keep only the feature attribute
b = all_grouped.select{ |k, v| k == 0 }[1].last.map(&:feature_id) # same with status == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a far cry from elegant, but to satisfy your requirements you could do something like this:

```
#model
class WF < ActiveRecord::Base

   def self.id_group_on_status
      a = WF.find_all_by_status(1).map(&:id)
      b = WF.find_all_by_status(0).map(&:id)
      a,b
   end
end

#somewhere else
a,b = WF.id_group_on_status
```